# Change focus and color when scroll cell in uitable

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, cell

i have this code for my tableview in tvOS project in swift 3, i want color cell when scroll it not focus! please can yon explain how do it?

this my code

```html
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tvChannelsArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    
    // Show TV Channels names
    cell.textLabel?.text = ((tvChannelsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "channel") as! String)
    
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "\(cell.textLabel!.text!)")
    
return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    channelsTableView.isHidden = false;

    return 100
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your tableview delegate implement the UISsrollViewDelegate method [ScrollViewDidScroll](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll)

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            if let currentCellPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell),
               let selectedCellPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                guard currentCellPath != selectedCellPath else {
                    continue
                }
            }
            let red = Float(cell.frame.origin.y / scrollView.contentSize.height)
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: red, green: 0.5, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: tableView say not found how change it?